# Working with global events for models, on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, events, eloquent

**It's basically what I need:** if any model row on my project is *created*, *updated* or *removed*, I need call a callback to work with this model row. I'll use that to create a changelog in other model, that will not trigger this global event to avoid looping.

**I tried set it like that:**

```
Model::creating($callback);
```

But it doesn't worked. Work only if I set it directly to all models that I have. It's bad because I need specific one-by-one. If I create a new one, I need specify it manually. Example:

```
User::creating($callback);
Company::creating($callback);
...
```

Any change will be logged on another model, called `Log`. It'll not trigger this `$callback`, because it'll register on table `logs` (managed by `Log`)  each change in other models. Something like:

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = "John";
$user->age = 18;
$user->save();

$user->name = "John Doe";
$user->save();

$user->delete();
$user->restore();
$user->forceDelete();
```

I'll register something like:

```
id | object_type | object_id | event_type | object_data
..   App\User      1           created      { name: John, age: 18 }
..   App\User      1           updated      { name: John Doe }
..   App\User      1           trashed      null
..   App\User      1           restored     null
..   App\User      1           removed      null
```

Comment: There's a fantastic package I've used for almost exactly your situation.  https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable

Comment: Have you looked into the boot method where you can listen to model events?

Comment: @mdamia I tried to use like `Model::{event}()` on boot, but it doesn't worked, only if I specify each model, like `User::{event}()`, `Company::{event}()`, ...

Comment: @user3158900 This package give a good idea for me: using Traits. So I can set where I need this feature. Will work fine to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3158900 Laravel Model Observers will do the trick, ti will observe create, update and delete events globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Eloquent model events have the format `eloquent.event:ClassName`.

You could subscribe to the `eloquent.*` event.
    Event::listen('eloquent.*', function($model) {});

Then you can check if the current model is a log model (in which case you'd `return true` straight out of it to avoid infinite recursion), otherwise, save the change to your log model.

Answer (score 2):

**With Laravel 5.1**

`BaseTrait` Trait:

```
trait BaseTrait
{
    public static function bootBaseTrait()
    {

        static:creating(function($item) {
            ....
        });

        static:updating(function($item) {
            ....
        });
    }

    // It binds the events in bootBaseTrait to any subclass
    // Base run first, then run your subclass's events if you defined on the subclass
}
```

`Base` Model:

```
use XX\XX\BaseTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Base extends Model
{
    use BaseTrait;
}
```

`XXX` Model:

```
use XX\XX\Base;

class XXX extends Base
{
}
```

**How does this work?**

You can see `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`

```
protected static function bootTraits()
```

The method tries to call `bootTraitName` when you use a trait!