# How to listen all updates in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to listen all models in Laravel for updated rows?

Laravel provides now to use AppServiceProvider, but only for specific model:

```
User::creating(function ($user) {
   return $user->isValid();
});
```

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, there's a `eloquent.updating` event you can subscribe to with `Event::listen`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with global events for models, on Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210959/working-with-global-events-for-models-on-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could extend your models from a base model (or use a trait) that makes use of a generic observer:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BaseModel extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        self::observe(ModelObserver::class);
    }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32338992/6158156) for more information.

Comment: `self::observe(ModelObserver::class);` this line throws undefined index <Model path> error

Comment: this throws this error: Undefined array key App\Models\BaseModel

Answer (score 1):

You can use `observers` for any models within your laravel application

[eloquent#observers documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers)

Comment: They're handy, but it sounds like OP wants to make *one* observer that listens to *all* models.

Comment: @ceejayoz ok, it's like impossible with the observers implementation within laravel actually. because each methods receives the model as their only argument.

Comment: Okay, I can use some observers (updated) for all models it brings duplication code

Comment: @OPV yes, but your point is very interesting to eliminate a duplication code

Comment: I tried return updated model to client: `  public function updated(Product $product)
    {
        $product->refresh();

        return response()->json($product);
    }` It does not work